# What is the selenium python client equivalent of this JavaScript document.getElementById('#searchboxinput').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('keyup'));

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

what is the python selenium equivalent of this JavaScript line?

```
document.getElementById('#searchboxinput').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('keyup'));
```

Comment: Just a note here... that looks incorrect... keyup is a keyboard event.  Should be mouseup?  .click() will generate mouseup right before click.  (list of events generated is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium Python client line of code to execute the *JavaScript*:

```
document.getElementById('#searchboxinput').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('keyup'));
```

will be:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('#searchboxinput').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('keyup'))")
```